# Difference in results between Cloud vision web entity api and their demo

Tags: google-cloud-vision

When I make a call to the cloud vision web entities detection I will get different results then when I use the exact same image on the demo side (https://cloud.google.com/vision/).

Api results:

```
"webEntities": [
  {
    "entityId": "/m/069b9z",
    "score": 28.432,
    "description": "Muiden Castle"
  },
  {
    "entityId": "/m/0k3p",
    "score": 9.7216,
    "description": "Amsterdam"
  },
  {
    "entityId": "/m/0gvtk97",
    "score": 4.6464,
    "description": "Pampus"
  },
  {
    "entityId": "/m/03w10h",
    "score": 4.5328,
    "description": "Stelling van Amsterdam"
  },
  {
    "entityId": "/m/04rjz",
    "score": 0.7232,
    "description": "Middle Ages"
  }
],
```

Demo result:

```
 "webDetection": {
    "webEntities": [
      {
        "entityId": "/m/069b9z",
        "score": 28.2912,
        "description": "Muiden Castle"
      },
      {
        "entityId": "/m/06jsf",
        "score": 23.7056,
        "description": "Rijksmuseum"
      },
      {
        "entityId": "/m/03w10h",
        "score": 4.2744,
        "description": "Stelling van Amsterdam"
      },
      {
        "entityId": "/m/0gvtk97",
        "score": 4.2264,
        "description": "Pampus"
      },
      {
        "entityId": "/g/11clg9rz1_",
        "score": 1.3836,
        "description": "Marina Muiderzand"
      },
      {
        "entityId": "/m/0w0r9",
        "score": 1.1220801,
        "description": "Muiden"
      },
      {
        "entityId": "/m/0grl_",
        "score": 0.7032,
        "description": "Château"
      },
      {
        "entityId": "/m/0d5gx",
        "score": 0.5525,
        "description": "Castle"
      },
      {
        "entityId": "/m/01k12m",
        "score": 0.5256,
        "description": "Dutch Golden Age"
      },
      {
        "entityId": "/t/23p50h_kgbnhm",
        "score": 0.5227
      },
      {
        "entityId": "/m/026gg32",
        "score": 0.3787,
        "description": "Water castle"
      },
      {
        "entityId": "/g/122lvp4h",
        "score": 0.3709,
        "description": "Dag van het Kasteel"
      },
      {
        "entityId": "/m/0pgl9",
        "score": 0.3558,
        "description": "Tourist attraction"
      },
      {
        "entityId": "/m/0k3p",
        "score": 0.103136,
        "description": "Amsterdam"
      },
      {
        "entityId": "/m/059j2",
        "score": 2.0908006e-11,
        "description": "Netherlands"
      }
    ],
```

This is how I add the image

```
    using (Image image = Image.FromFile(filePath))
    {
        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

            request.Requests[0].Image.Content = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        }
    }
```

This happens with almost all images.

As far as I know of the only option you have, when calling the web entity detection api is the amount of results you want. But the amount has no effect on the kind of results.

The api's Label detection and landmark detection give the same answers as the demo.

Has anybody seen this behavior too? 
Are there other options I missed?

**Edit:**
Request body:

```
{
    "requests":[
    {
        "features":[
        {
            "type": "LABEL_DETECTION",
            "maxResults":5
        },
        {
            "type":"LANDMARK_DETECTION",
            "maxResults":1
        },
        {
            "type":"WEB_DETECTION",
            "maxResults":5
        }
        ],
        "image":
        {
            "content":"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"
        }
    }
    ] }
```

**Edit 2:**
Endpoint: https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate
I do not use a SDK.

**Edit 3:**
the image I used: https://www.muiderslot.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/DSC5093-Muiderslot-poster.jpg
Strange thing is that I just tested the image again and now the demo also gives as second description "Amsterdam" but the 5th description is still different.

But this image still gives bigger differences: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdYk0.jpg

Comment: can you please post the request body of your request when you use the API and also the code you use?

Comment: @Peshmerge, I added the request body. I did not post my code because I get results, so I assume my way of calling the api is ok.

Comment: Can you send me the image? or a link to the image?

Comment: Can you please provide the API endpoint you are calling? 
You don't use a specific Google Vision SDK right?

Comment: It gives indeed different responses back, even if I copy the request body of the Demo site (using Google DevTools) and resend it to the Google API using Postman! It's really strange!
I thought in the beginning it has to do with the maxResults parameter! Nope, after editing the parameter, it still different!

Comment: Yep, I played with the maxResults too. No effect. Thnx for the effort you put in it. Our customers will most likely test the new functionality with the demo. Lets hope they don't use images that show these differences.

Comment: Even using the API with the same image, you will get different results!
Check this question on Google Forums 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/cloud-vision-discuss/gbHzEjn5SjI